# Cant find a solution for this query

Tags: mysql

I got this tables:

```
Students (Name);

Exam (IDExam)

Exams_Prenotations(StudentName,Exam)
```

I want all the students that do the same exams as the student named 'Bob'. (If bob does the exam 'EXAM1' and 'EXAM2' i want all the students that will do the 'EXAM1' and 'EXAM2' with him).

I **CANT** USE SUBQUERIES.

Thank you

Comment: And the question is…?

Comment: After rereading the question at least five times, I felt like asking you, [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: the query is? :D i v tried nothing since all the Ideas i got are based on subqueries

Comment: you can't do sub-queries... but what _can_ you do?  can you use temporary tables and a second query?

Comment: **Why** can't you use subqueries? Was this a condition of your homework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't said what it is you *can* do, nor given much detail regarding the three tables you mentioned, so I've made some assumptions.

Also, for the purposes of building a quick demonstration, it's in **sqlite**, rather than mysql, but the queries should be more or less the same.

**structure of data:**

```
sqlite> select * from students;
id          name      
----------  ----------
1           alice       
2           bob     
3           charles   
4           dave    

sqlite> select * from exam;
id          name      
----------  ----------
1           maths     
2           art       
3           physics 


sqlite> select * from exams_prenotations;
student_id  exam_id   
----------  ----------
1           1         
1           3         
2           1         
2           3         
3           2         
4           2
```

then we're creating a temporary table with these tables to hold the exam ids for Bob's exams:

```
create temporary table bob_exams as 
  select x.id 
    from exam x 
    join exams_prenotations e on e.exam_id = x.id 
    join students s on s.id = e.student_id 
   where s.name = "bob";

sqlite> select * from bob_exams;
id        
----------
1         
3
```

...and now joining the temporary table to the originals, we can get the students doing the same exam as Bob:

```
select s.name 
  from exam x 
  join exams_prenotations e on e.exam_id = x.id 
  join students s on s.id = e.student_id 
  join bob_exams b on b.id = x.id 
group by s.name;

name      
----------
alice     
bob
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like below:

```
SELECT *
  FROM
    STUDENTS s
    INNER JOIN EXAMS_STUDENTS es ON es.student_id = s.id
    INNER JOIN EXAMS e ON e.id = es.exam_id
WHERE
  s.name = 'Bob'
```

If that is not what you are looking; then, you need to reformulate your questions. Data structure   would also help.

Comment: I need ALL the students that do the same exams as BOB. So if BOB does the EXAM 1 and EXAM 2 i need all the students that DO the EXAM 1 and EXAM 2. If bob does not the EXAM 3 i dont want the users that do the EXAM 3 . Sry for my bad english